# Functional way to map a geometric series in Swift

Tags: swift

I have an array of size `n`. I would like to fill it with values from a geometric series with a functional approach.
What function should I use?

The result should be an array such as :

```
[a, a^2, a^3, ... a^n]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`sequence(first:next:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2015879-sequence) to compute powers
of `a` by repeated multiplication, limit the (lazily evaluated) sequence with [`prefix(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2886011-prefix) to the desired number of  entries, and then create an array from the truncated sequence. Example:

```
let a = 0.5   // The base
let n = 4     // The maximal exponent

let series = Array(sequence(first: a, next: { $0 * a }).prefix(n))
print(series) // [0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.0625]
```

Another option can be to enumerate the sequence without creating an
actual array:

```
for x in sequence(first: a, next: { $0 * a }).prefix(n) {
    // do something with `x`
}
```

Comment: In the `for x in sequence` example, you can also leave off the `prefix` and then use some condition in the loop to decide when to `break` the loop.

Comment: *Print the powers of 2 less than 1000*: `for x in sequence(first: 1, next: { $0 * 2 }) {
    guard x < 1000 else { break };
    print(x)
}`

Comment: What is the best way to do it ? your solution or the solution proposed by Pastzor ? I seems to me that with the sequence, I will create a very long sequence and then truncate it to the desired size. So the ().map solution seems better. Do you agree ?

Comment: The *very long sequence* is lazily evaluated, meaning the elements aren't computed until they are needed.  The `prefix` in this case tells it how many to compute, so this should be about the same efficiency as `map` except that it is using multiplication instead of `pow` and multiplication is probably a tad bit more efficient.

Comment: thks! Now, I have also to fill a double array entry (matrix) for which each element is of the following form : c(i,j) = (i+j+2.min(i,j)). Any idea if there is a similar shortcut for that ?

Comment: That sounds like it should be another StackOverflow question.  Please show how you're doing it now.

Comment: @vacawama: For the power of 2 less than 1000 I would use `for x in sequence(first: 1, next: { $0 * 2 }).prefix(while: { $0 < 1000 }) { ... }`

Comment: @MartinR, that is a good way to do it.  Mine was just a toy example to show that the loop body could decide when to truncate the infinite sequence.  The condition for ending could be quite complex.

Answer (score 1):

You can create such geometric series by simply calling `map` on a range and doing the power operation inside `map`.

```
func createGeometricSeries(ofSize n:Int, _ a:Int)->[Int]{
    return (1...n).map({Int(pow(Double(a), Double($0)))})
}

createGeometricSeries(ofSize: 3,2) //[2,4,8]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **map** for that,

```
let resultingArray = yourArray.map({ a * $0 })
```

resulting array is the array that will meet your requirement

You can find more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2908681-map) in Apple Documentation.